# Set up gitattributes by command line

Tags: git, command-line, zip, git-config

A colleague of mine wants to be able to version zip files (.docx, .xlsx, etc.) and for that he has to add

```
[diff "zip"]
    textconv = unzip -c -a
```

to his gitconfig file.

No problem for me, but my colleague, who is a beginner in git, would like me to give him a simple command line that he can copy/paste without having to think.

I (naively) tried running `git config --global "diff \"zip\".textconv" "unzip -c -a"` from the command line, but I received an `error: invalid key: diff "zip".textconv` in return. Too bad, I tried.

Is there a simple way to acheive what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git config --global diff.zip.textconv "unzip -c -a"
```

`git config` splits `diff.zip.textconv` itself.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that! Git amazes me every day.